# Make a thread wait for either a Timer or a Signal?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, signals

I am writing a Multithreaded Python application, in which each thread should wake up under the following circumstances:

1. A signal from a main thread
2. A Timer call started by itself

In other words, threads should wake up according to a timer they set for themselves, and be able to respond to a signal from a managing thread whenever a relevant event appears.

What's the idiomatic way to implement a dual (Timer/Event) wake-up mechanism?

Comment: What's the right way to combine it with signals? Are there any caveats?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event), has a [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait) method, which takes a timeout.  So you could do something as simple as

In main thread:

```
sleepEvent = threading.Event()
```

pass that to your other threads, and in them:

```
sleepEvent.wait(10) # wait for up to 10 seconds
```

Now your thread will either wait 10 seconds (like a timer) or will clear the wait if the main thread calls

```
sleepEvent.set()
```