# Take screenshots at same time Xvfb multiple displays

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a requirement where I am running a selenium script which opens up 2 instances of Firefox on a machine. I want to take screenshots of both instances at the **same time**. The same time part is important.

I used following steps to simulate this:

1. Start 2 different displays using `Xvfb -ac :99 and Xvfb -ac :100`
2. I have 2 python scripts which sets environment variable DISPLAY to 99 and 100 respectively.

Here are the python scripts:
**screenshot99.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':99'

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.test.com')
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

and **screenshot100.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':100'

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.test.com')
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it even possible to take screenshots of 2 different instances of browser at the **same time**?
2. If yes, how can I simulate that? I just need a Proof Of Concept to prove the above fact.

Comment: You can fork two processes or threads that will take the screenshots upon receiving a signal, and make the parent process send the signals. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463626/make-a-thread-wait-for-either-a-timer-or-a-signal).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash file telling to spawn two processes in the background, this guarantees you concurrency but not parallelism.

```
python screenshot99.py &
python screenshot100.py &
```

What you can do is use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module to create a turnstile lock -

EDIT - I should specify **even** this won't guarantee parallelism but this is closer. You'll have to specify the CPU to run on if you want that.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def f(i, counter):
    counter.value += 1
    while counter.value != 2 :
        print 'aquiring...'
    ####  CRITICAL SECTION #### 
    # spawn your script here using the os module or
    # just write the code in here 
    print int(round(time.time() * 1000)), i
    #### CRITICAL SECTION END ####

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    for num in range(2):
        Process(target=f, args=(num, counter)).start()
```

Results -

```
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
aquiring...
1487866323038 0
1487866323038 1
```

I repeated this multiple times (showing just the time)-

```
1487866388886 0
1487866388886 1
```

Again -

```
1487866398492 0
1487866398492 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand the spawning part. Spawn which script? The bash script?

Comment: Your `screenshot.py` file. [or just write the code inline]

Comment: This'll work only if you can access the same display port at the same time. If not I don't think its possible to guarantee parallelism. In that case you'll have to go with the bash script solution.

Comment: But same display port can't run two websites at the same time in different browsers and give me screenshots of both websites at the same time. On the same display port, one will be hidden by the other.

Comment: I'm passing `num` as a param, why not use it as a parameter for the display port? I think it should work.

Comment: I also figured out one thing. Even if both scripts start concurrently and I take screenshot after browser.get('http://www.test.com') by calling browser.save_screenshot('xyz.png'), it might lose concurrency while taking screenshots. Because 2 instances of same browser can take different times to load the same page. I actually want concurrency after browser.get('http://www.test.com'). Once both the scripts have loaded the webpage, start taking screenshot.

Comment: Ugly fix - Make both the processes sleep for x seconds if you can guarantee the pages will open up within x seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136481/discussion-between-hashcode55-and-skjindal93).